# Writing Htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I am completely nube with htaccess rewriting. Today I am stuck with a problem..

I want my url  **www.try.com/formal-shoes.php?catId=2** to show as **www.try.com/second**

second one **www.try.com/formal-shoes.php?catId=1** to show as **www.try.com/first** Like this. Please help me to do so. what shall be rule...

As by hit and trial I wrote

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteRule formal-shoes.php?catId=2 second/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking at this the wrong way! Your rewrite rule should be like:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^/second$ index.php?catId=2 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^/first$ index.php?catId=1 [QSA,L]
```

Note: We are rewriting the expected url to the actual url. Also, `RewriteEngine on` is mandatory!

PS. Its Noob not nube :)